# How to assign value to object member using variable in TS

Tags: typescript

Object:

```
  export class PartyDto {
  partyType: string;
  title: string;
  preferredContactMethod: string;
  alternateContactMethod: string;
  preferredContactTime: string;
  firstName: string;
  surname: string;
  singleLineAddress: string;
  manualAddress: boolean;
  internationalAddress: boolean;
  unmatchedAddress: string;
  postalAddr: string;
  suburb: string;
  state: string;
  postcode: string;
  internationalState: string;
  country: string;
  mobilePhoneNo: string;
  homePhoneNo: string;
  workPhoneNo: string;
  homeEmailAddr: string;
  workEmailAddr: string;
  organisation: string;
  customerFlag: string;
}
```

In TS file i am trying to pass contact method which could be homePhoneNo/ mobilePhoneNo and assign blank value to selected. Ex. if 'mobilePhonerNo' is passed as contact method then want to change partyDto.mobilePhoneNo to blank value.

Below code gives me error as contact type doesn't exist in PartyDto( which could be homePhoneNo/ mobilePhoneNo )

```
export class PartyDetailsComponent {

  @Input()
  parties: Array<PartyDto>;

  @Input()
  party: PartyDto;

 changePreferredContactMethod() {
    this.clearContactMethodValues(this.party.preferredContactMethod);
 }

 clearContactMethodValues(method: string) {
   if(method !== 'Letter') {
   var contactType = this.camelize(method);    
   this.party.contactType = ''; //error as contact type doesn't exist in PartyDto( which could be homePhoneNo/ mobilePhoneNo )
          
        } 
}
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the whole class?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see what exactly you're trying to do, but I think you want to have a property called `contactType` that's an enum.

```
enum ContactType {
  homePhoneNo,
  mobilePhoneNo
}

export class PartyDto {
  partyType: string;
  title: string;
  preferredContactMethod: string;
  alternateContactMethod: string;
  preferredContactTime: string;
  firstName: string;
  surname: string;
  singleLineAddress: string;
  manualAddress: boolean;
  internationalAddress: boolean;
  unmatchedAddress: string;
  postalAddr: string;
  suburb: string;
  state: string;
  postcode: string;
  internationalState: string;
  country: string;
  mobilePhoneNo: string;
  homePhoneNo: string;
  workPhoneNo: string;
  homeEmailAddr: string;
  workEmailAddr: string;
  organisation: string;
  customerFlag: string;
  contactType: ContactType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am still not getting how to make partyDTO field blank if I have field name in variable

Comment: Can you just delete the property from the object, instead of making it an empty string?